# Powershell XML variable name from other variable value

Tags: powershell

In my script, I'm reading files from a folder with get-childitem.
I want to use the basename of each file to create a new XML variable.
Unfortunately I'm getting the following error: `The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.`

This is a snippet of the code:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    [xml]$($file.BaseName) = Get-Content $file.FullName
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do not use dynamic variable names. Period. It creates more problems than you believe you can solve by using them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is in your files, but you could try the following:

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    New-Variable -Name $file.BaseName -Value [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName -raw)
}
```

Then you can use the following to retrieve the value of those variables. Obviously you can reference them directly by name if you know them:

```
Get-Variable -Name $file.BaseName -ValueOnly
```